# Why are my results returned twice?

Tags: mysql, query, performance, query-performance

I've this query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT `default_wall_posts_comments`.`c_id` as c_id,
  `default_wall_posts_comments`.`comments` as comments, 
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - default_wall_posts_comments.date_created AS pass_time_comment, 
  `default_profiles`.*, `default_wall_posts`.*, 
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - default_wall_posts.date_created AS pass_time
 FROM (`default_wall_posts`)
 LEFT JOIN `default_profiles` 
    ON `default_profiles`.`user_id` = `default_wall_posts`.`userid`
 LEFT JOIN `default_wall_posts_comments` 
    ON `default_wall_posts`.`p_id` = `default_wall_posts_comments`.`post_id`
 WHERE `default_wall_posts`.`userid` =  '1'
 ORDER BY `default_wall_posts`.`date_created` DESC LIMIT 7
```

But results for the main table which is `default_wall_posts` are repeated for each `default_wall_posts_comments`.

I'm trying to get all comments for one `default_wall_posts`. Can be this query optimized in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of left join try inner join, take a look to this [graphic](http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&client=firefox-a&sa=N&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=fflb&biw=1680&bih=915&tbm=isch&tbnid=SXGHjyoV2uc_DM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.theprogrammersguide.com/tag/mysql-join-syntax/&docid=AKR9K-FXdwjq0M&imgurl=http://www.theprogrammersguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/mysql-join-qery-subquery.jpg&w=966&h=760&ei=yyKsT_DbDcT0ggfWvMzMAQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=175&vpy=144&dur=574&hovh=199&hovw=253&tx=145&ty=124&sig=109906331941566321229&page=1&tbnh=128&tbnw=163&start=0&ndsp=42&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0,i:75), and if you want to paginate you should use:
`limit start_INT, number_int_per_result`

Example

```
jcho360> select * from actor limit 0,5;
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name    | last_update         |
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|        1 | PENELOPE   | GUINESS      | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        2 | NICK       | WAHLBERG     | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        3 | ED         | CHASE        | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        4 | JENNIFER   | DAVIS        | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        5 | JOHNNY     | LOLLOBRIGIDA | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

jcho360> select * from actor limit 5,5;
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name | last_update         |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
|        6 | BETTE      | NICHOLSON | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        7 | GRACE      | MOSTEL    | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        8 | MATTHEW    | JOHANSSON | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        9 | JOE        | SWANK     | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|       10 | CHRISTIAN  | GABLE     | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

jcho360> select * from actor limit 10,5;
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name | last_update         |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
|       11 | ZERO       | CAGE      | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|       12 | KARL       | BERRY     | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|       13 | UMA        | WOOD      | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|       14 | VIVIEN     | BERGEN    | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|       15 | CUBA       | OLIVIER   | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Nice and thanks I'll try tomorrow from office

Answer (score 3):

That's how joins work!  Don't select the wall posts in the same query if you just want the comments.

Comment: Hmmm what about if I want to use that query for paginate results? See the LIMIT ... Should work fine?